# Showing no such column error on running Android Application SQLite

Tags: android

This is my MainActivity file.

```
package com.example.applicationmy;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.ApplicationMy.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
     // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
     myDbHelper.create();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
     throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
     // open the database
     myDbHelper.open();
     myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
     throw sqle;
    }

    Cursor c = myDbHelper.getUser(1);
    Toast.makeText(this,
     "id: " + c.getInt(0)+ "\n NO: " + c.getString(1)
     + "\n FROM: " + c.getString(2) + "\n TO: "
     + c.getString(3) + "\n VIA: "
             + c.getString(4) + "\n LENGTH "
                     + c.getFloat(5), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    c.close();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();


    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.From);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void sendAnotherMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RouteNo);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}







/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

and this is my DatabaseHelper class to read from the database.

```
package com.example.applicationmy;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "route.sqlite";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Routedet";
 private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
 private static final String COLUMN_Route_no = "Route_no";
 private static final String COLUMN_Route_location = "Route_location";
 private static final String COLUMN_Route_dest = "Route_dest";
 private static final String COLUMN_Route_via = "Route_via";
 private static final String COLUMN_Route_len = "Route_len";


 private SQLiteDatabase database;

 private final Context context;

 // database path
 private static String DATABASE_PATH;

 /** construcRoute_destr */
 public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx) {
  super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  this.context = ctx;
  DATABASE_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()
    + "/databases/";

 }

 /**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
  * database.
  * */
 public void create() throws IOException {
  boolean check = checkDataBase();

  SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

  // Creates empty database default system path
  db_Read = this.getWritableDatabase();
  db_Read.close();
  try {
   if (!check) {
    copyDataBase();
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   throw new Error("Error copying database");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Check if the database already exist Route_dest avoid re-copying the file each
  * time you open the application.
  * 
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
 private boolean checkDataBase() {
  SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
  try {
   String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
   checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
  } catch (SQLiteException e) {
   // database does't exist yet.
  }

  if (checkDB != null) {
   checkDB.close();
  }
  return checkDB != null ? true : false;
 }

 /**
  * Copies your database Route_location your local assets-folder Route_dest the just created
  * empty database in the system folder, Route_location where it can be accessed and
  * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

  // Open your local db as the input stream
  InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

  // Path Route_dest the just created empty db
  String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

  // Open the empty db as the output stream
  OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

  // transfer bytes Route_location the inputfile Route_dest the outputfile
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int Route_len;
  while ((Route_len = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
   myOutput.write(buffer, 0, Route_len);
  }

  // Close the streams
  myOutput.flush();
  myOutput.close();
  myInput.close();

 }

 /** open the database */
 public void open() throws SQLException {
  String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
  database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
 }

 /** close the database */
 @Override
 public synchronized void close() {
  if (database != null)
   database.close();
  super.close();
 }



 // retrieves a particular user
 public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
  Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
    COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_Route_no, COLUMN_Route_location, COLUMN_Route_dest, COLUMN_Route_via, COLUMN_Route_len},
    COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }

  return mCursor;
 }

 // delete a particular user
 public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
  return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
 }

 // retrieves all users
 public Cursor getAllUsers() {
  return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_Route_no, COLUMN_Route_location, COLUMN_Route_dest, COLUMN_Route_via, COLUMN_Route_len }, null, null,
    null, null, null);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
  // Route_destDO AuRoute_dest-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // Route_destDO AuRoute_dest-generated method stub

 }

}
```

and here is logcat ouput. Please help me as soon as possible. I am stuck on this from over a day. I have to submit my project tomorrow. Please help

```
04-27 12:27:33.339: E/SQLiteLog(2384): (1) no such column: Route_no
04-27 12:27:33.349: D/AndroidRuntime(2384): Shutting down VM
04-27 12:27:33.349: W/dalvikvm(2384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a17ba8)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384): Process: com.example.applicationmy, PID: 2384
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.applicationmy/com.example.applicationmy.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Route_no (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, Route_no, Route_location, Route_dest, Route_via, Route_len FROM Routedet WHERE _id = 1
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Route_no (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, Route_no, Route_location, Route_dest, Route_via, Route_len FROM Routedet WHERE _id = 1
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at com.example.applicationmy.DataBaseHelper.getUser(DataBaseHelper.java:138)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at com.example.applicationmy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-27 12:27:33.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2384):     ... 11 more
04-27 12:27:37.759: I/Process(2384): Sending signal. PID: 2384 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: I think 139th line of Database Helper. But I have column Route_no in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your table does not contain the column in question. (Route_no).

The likely causes are either your create table statement missed out the column definition, or if you added that column after the rest of the database then you haven't incremented the database version to cause it to update the schema.

**Edit**: If you replace the projection param with a null and then print out what you get using

```
Log.d(TAG, DatabaseUtils.dumpCursortToString(c));
```

It should help you debug your issue

Comment: Or he's pointed at the wrong database.  Or...

Comment: Well the error is when looking for a column and the table names match so that's a lot less likely...

Comment: never mind it worked. I deleted my previous emulator and made a new one. I changed the name of my columns while working on the previous emulator

Comment: Well as I mentioned, if you change your schema in future, increment the DATABASE_VERSION (that's what it is there for, it triggers the content provider to update your schema for you!)

Comment: okay i will keep that in mind for sure